# How do I use filter for Count in Django annotate()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

So I've seen lots of posts dealing with the same question, but most of them were outdated(Django versions) and I couldn't find anything helpful. So the problem is, I was trying to use filter for Count in Django annotation. Below is an example, and I've tried three variances that I found after Googling.

```
all_posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(
    count_comments = Count('user_comment', validated=True), #1
    count_comments = Count('user_comment').filter(validated=True), #2
    count_comments = Count('user_comment', filter=Q(validated=True)), #3
)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the number of comments that are validated. But obviously none of them works. What is the correct way of using the filter?

Comment: Can you add your models to the question? Probably something like this would work `count_comments=Count('user_comment', filter=Q(user_comment__validated=True))`

Answer (score 0):

`It helps`

```
    all_posts = Post.objects.filter(validated = True).annotate(count_coments = Count('user_coment'))
```